# SSIS FTP Task - Downloading source files approach

Tags: ftp, ssis

Im to develop a SSIS package that have to download a list of files from a FTP location.Although the frequency and timings of retrieving the generated files have been agreed upon with the client .

I noticed many times that when connecting , the user files (CSV) are being created (size gradually increasing) and that those downloaded are partially complete in content.
One suggestion i received was to have a *"check file"* a file which would be created and the end of the files creation by the client which would inform me that the file are ready to be downloaded,should it not be found no download shall happen.

However, i would like to know if other options are available ,which can be integrated in SSIS.

Thanks

Comment: One alternative, if this is available in your office and with your client, is to have the client modify their job to send an email when the file is complete.  The email would state "job is complete" and would be received by SQLMail on your side.  This would trigger a job that launches your SSIS package to import the completed file from FTP.  With this approach there is no need to continually monitor the CSV file for "check file".

Comment: It seems that the SQL Mail feature is discontinued in the recent version of SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would follow the 'check file' pattern.  I would not introduce a new communications mode (e.g. email) which implies further complexity and configuration.

Lately for FTP tasks I have been calling WinSCP rather than using the SSIS FTP Task. It has better functionality.  Here's their info on this topic:

http://winscp.net/eng/docs/script_checking_file_existence

Comment: Thanks Mike, as it seems the check file pattern remain the best option so far.